# Django importError (cannot import name 'six')

Tags: django, six

serializer.py:

```
from .models import stock
from rest_framework import serializers


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = stock
        fields = ('id', 'stock_name', 'price', 'stock_gain', 'market_name')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .seriaizer import StockSerializer
from .models import stock
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


class StockViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('stock_name',)
    ordering = ('stock_gain',)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from restapp.views import StockViews
from restapp import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('stock', views.StockViews)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

this error comes to me:
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\hajar\OneDrive\Desktop\stockm\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils_*init*_.py)

i installes six
pip install six

but not work???? may any one can help my?!

Answer (score 0):

this error may be due to the older versions of the dependencies that you use in your project like `djangorestframework` or `django-cors-headers`. Please upgrade those to the latest version. The following may help

`pip install --upgrade django-cors-headers`  
`pip install --upgrade djangorestframework`